# React Native: Radial Gradient Background

Tags: react-native, styles, radial-gradients

Is there an package, or another way to have a simple, let's say blue to blueish,  radial gradient background, for one of the views?

I've tried [react-native-radial-gradient](https://github.com/surajitsarkar19/react-native-radial-gradient), but it seems like it's outdated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably you can use [RadialGradient](https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-image-filter-kit/blob/master/docs/generators.md#radialgradient) from my [react-native-image-filter-kit](https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-image-filter-kit) package. Note that gradients from react-native-image-filter-kit are initially designed as primitives for blending with other images and your case is not something that was taken into account in the first place.

```
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import {
  RadialGradient,
  ImageBackgroundPlaceholder
} from 'react-native-image-filter-kit'

const imageStyle = { width: 320, height: 320 }

const gradient = (
  <RadialGradient
    colors={['red', '#00ff00', 'blue']}
    stops={[0, 0.5, 1]}
    image={
      <ImageBackgroundPlaceholder style={imageStyle}>
        /* your content here */
      </ImageBackgroundPlaceholder>
    }
  />
)
```

[image: result]

Comment: This fixed my problem with transparent colors in `react-native-radial-gradient`. Great repo, thanks!

Comment: Oh my, you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

You can also created your own radial gradient from `react-native-svg` package

```
import { Defs, Stop, Svg, RadialGradient as SVGRadialGradient, Path } from 'react-native-svg'

export function RadialGradient() {
  return (
    <Svg
      height="100%"
      width="100%"
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
      }}
    >
      <Path
        d="M0 0H375V279C375 283.418 371.418 287 367 287H8C3.58172 287 0 283.418 0 279V0Z"
        fill="url(#grad)"
      />
      <Defs>
        <SVGRadialGradient
          id="grad"
          cx="0"
          cy="0"
          r="1"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          gradientTransform="translate(187.5 50.5) rotate(90) scale(180 350.061)"
        >
          <Stop stopColor={'#3730A3'} />
          <Stop stopColor={'#0F0E26'} offset={1} />
        </SVGRadialGradient>
      </Defs>
    </Svg>
  )
}
```