# How to get circular gradient in react native?

Tags: react-native, gradient

How can I get this gradient effect inside a circular view in react native?

[image]

The two gradient colors are : `#350078` and `#00FFFF`

Comment: You can use any CSS gradient generator and then translate the it to react style object using this tool: https://csstox.surge.sh/ 
Your gradient style could look like this: `{ "background": "radial-gradient(#350078, 00FFFF)" }`

Comment: This might Help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604241/react-native-radial-gradient-background

Comment: @Pramod I tried that, link but I am getting boxes, not proper circle

Comment: @Papooch, thanks for the solution, I tried the method, but I am getting just one color, not both colors in gradient

Comment: @HarshitG24 Sorry, I forgot the # sign before the second color, does it also not work with it?

Answer (score 1):

Use "react-native-radial-gradient" it worked for me

[image: Screenshot of emulator]

```
import RadialGradient from 'react-native-radial-gradient';

<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center' }}>

        <RadialGradient style={{width:200,height:200,  opacity:0.5}}
                        colors={['#350078','#00FFFF','transparent']}
                        stops={[0,0, 0.5]}
                        center={[100,100]}
                        radius={100}>

        </RadialGradient>


        </View>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, just that I had to make some minute changes to stops and inside stylesheet, backgroundColor: 'transparent', as i needed a transparent background. Thanks for the kind help!!!